# Changing the time based on the time zone but R doesn't recognize CEST

Tags: r

I have a long list of times (UTC) which I wish to convert to local time, which in this instance is CEST. To do this I have been using `with_tz("2023-02-05 08:50:00", tzone = "Europe/Madrid")` or 'with_tz("2023-02-05 08:50:00", tzone = "CET")' which returns a time 1 hour forward of `2023-02-05 09:50:00` however during the daylight savings months R doesn't recognize that we are in fact in CEST and the time being returned should be `2023-02-05 10:50:00`. Ihave been using 'OlsonNames()' to get a list of all the recognized timezones but cant seem to see CEST on there so does anyone have a fix or an alternative for this?

Comment: You could perhaps use the `lubridate::dst` function to stick with CET and adjust by an hour if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine and recognise the CET vs CEST where appropriate:

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct("2023-05-22 11:11:11", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
t2 <- as.POSIXct("2023-02-22 11:11:11", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
lubridate::with_tz(c(t1, t2), tzone = 'Europe/Berlin')
[1] "2023-05-22 13:11:11 CEST" "2023-02-22 12:11:11 CET"
```

also so does this:

```
lubridate::with_tz(c(t1, t2), tzone = 'Europe/Madrid')
[1] "2023-05-22 13:11:11 CEST" "2023-02-22 12:11:11 CET"
```

Perhaps check your dates or code? or give a reproducible example.